# Dead store when using initWithCapacity in an array

Tags: ios, arrays

The title says it all. Here is where my `deadstore` warning is :

```
//"objects" is just an array that I have above
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[objects count]];
arr = [methodReturningAnArray:withArrayParam];   //i give "objects" as param
```

And it says the `value stored during the initialization is never read` on the `[[alloc]init]` line.

But i've read that giving array a defined size during init is more optimal, and here i can afford it. Is there something i'm doing wrong or is there some magic involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize `arr` with a value here:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[objects count]];
```

Then you immediately overwrite that value and assign it a *new* value here:

```
arr = [methodReturningAnArray:withArrayParam];
```

Instead, just do:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [methodReturningAnArray:withArrayParam];
```

Initializing a `NSMutableArray` with a capacity is optimal if you are modifying the individual elements of the array. What you have done here is replace the array wholesale.

Comment: But the thing is, i don't assign any value, just a capacity size !
Is the size considered a value? Is that size completly ignored at the next line?

Comment: No, you *do* assign a value. The value you assign is `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[objects count]]`.

Comment: When you `alloc init` a class, you get an instance of that class back. `NSMutableArray` is a class in Objective-C; this isn't like `int[] c_array = int[6];` in C. `NSMutableArray *arr` is a pointer to an object that has methods and properties.

Comment: aaaaallright. Well thanks man ! I kinda knew I had to replace this bit but I wanted to know why because this seemed confusing.
Thanks for your time, have a good day :)